# Public key not working... but it matches the host key

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I want to connect with my raspberry pi from my mac, I can do it from a mac with 10.10, I copied the public keys but I get this trying to login from another mac:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.12 [10.0.0.12] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa,.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa,.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA f2:2c:92:e7:76:81:5e:a0:a9:b8:e8:e0:4e:c4:a0:bc
debug1: Host '10.0.0.12' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Gerardo/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: .ssh/id_rsa,.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pi@10.0.0.12's password:
```

It looks like the key is fine, but still asks me for my password... Any help!?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem on a mac.  If you run `ls -l` on the keyfiles, do you see an `@` sign in the permissions line?  If not, your extended attributes aren't set correctly.  I recommend just generating the keyfile on the mac you're going to use it on.

Comment: In your log in lines 6 and 7 you only have private keys of type -1. Have you generated the keys on the mac?

Comment: Yes I have generated the key from my mac,  with the same results.... That's why I copied it from the one that is working, but no luck...

Comment: please, post the content of your config file or command you are running. You have there probably something like `-i .ssh/id_rsa,.ssh/id_dsa` which is obviously not recognized as path and therefore not used.

Comment: Jakuje, I don't know what config file you are talking about... can you please give me more info?

Comment: Foam:.ssh Gerardo$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-------@ 1 Gerardo  staff  1679 Apr 17  2015 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Gerardo  staff   388 Apr 17  2015 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Gerardo  staff  1173 Apr 17  2015 known_hosts

Comment: "or command you are running" is important part of my question, if you don't have any config file

Comment: This is the command: ssh pi@10.0.0.12

Comment: Hmm ... and content of  `/etc/ssh_config`? There must be somewhere written `.ssh/id_rsa,.ssh/id_dsa`

Comment: I found this:#   IdentitiesOnly no
    IdentityFile .ssh/id_rsa,.ssh/id_dsa
#   IPQoS lowdelay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
 IdentityFile .ssh/id_rsa,.ssh/id_dsa
```

in your `/etc/ssh_config` with

```
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

if your private key is placed in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: Same results :(

Comment: can't be. Edit your question with the updated verbose log, preferably `ssh -vvv pi@10.0.0.12`.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake! I was trying different stuff.... But now it works with your solution! Thanks a lot Jakuje!

Comment: [;)] Choosing as a solution would be appreciated.